# Automated QA for a single freelance developer?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, testing

I have been developing an application in my free time using Qt.
As the size of code is increasing I am finding it difficult to contain new bugs for older code. I have been testing my application manually.
Since the target is an exe I cannot test it automated with C++ tests without injecting some extra code into my application.

So my question is, what is the best QA technique for a GUI application if you are a single developer & wont be earning money from the project as it will be released for free?
Thank You.

**EDIT:**
I would like to have a set of simple tests, each testing for specific functionalities of my software. I would like them to run automatically one after another. Finally they should create a report of which tests failed. This can possibly be done by creating new functions in the same classes + adding some checks in existing functions I want to test & then create a new class which will have all the tests. So I wanted to know whether is this the best way or is there a better alternative? Because everytime I will build a release target, I will be commenting/deleting this QA code, which may create some bugs for that build.

Currently I am not worried about documentation & comments as I have maintained that from the beginning. It is only about source code QA.

Comment: Did you consider making our application a [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. with its source code visible on http://github.com/ so that others could glance at your code and give interesting feedback)? Don't be shy, publish your source code even if it is still buggy or incomplete!

Comment: I considered making my software, OSS. But I think it is all very complicated, the push, pull, etc. Never understood what that meant. Plus I was considering making it OSS if the user base becomes respectable, otherwise it would be very difficult to attract developers. What do you say on this?

Comment: You won't have any users if you don't publish your software as free software. And learning about version control is useful (even for proprietary software). `git` has very nice [tutorial documantation about `git`](http://git-scm.com/documentation) including short videos.

Comment: The software is free to use (no price)! But it is not open source. That is what I meant.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to be less opinion based? The degree of test coverage is inversely proportional to development time. You can combine testing with design and documentation by writing tests first, then implementations (based on tests), and include tests as examples in the documentation. You can read about QtTests here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial1.html

Comment: @Cool_Coder: here you can learn git: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL782E6284B60DD0B2 you will love it ;)

Comment: But you won't have much users, because few users will download your binary (and making a binary only release requires a lot of trust from your users: how do they know it is not adware or malware?). Publishing the source code might bring you a few users and perhaps contributors.

Comment: BTW, you could use preprocessor directives to avoid your code for release builds.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, thanks for that suggestion! I almost forgot about that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit tests by-the-book will only give you assurance for your methods, not for the entire application. But you can also use the same unit-test framework to write acceptance tests for specific capabilities of the application.

The easiest way to go would be to extract the GUI from the application, and to make the GUI dependent of an API/library. The API will make it easy to write functional tests. Be sure to make the GUI as thin as possible.

I wouldn't add test code to your class and remove it to release, I think this is as risky as shipping with the test code. You're better off have separated source as already advised here.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is getting large enough, you'll probably want to create some unit tests for it (I like the free `CppUnit` library, which is similar to `JUnit`; also Jo Are By suggested `QtTest`, which presumably is available with `Qt`).

Even if you have to make some changes to your production code, it will be worth your time in the end.

You may also wish to look into automated GUI testing frameworks for `Qt` applications; I'm not familiar with any of these.

Comment: As the OP is using `Qt`, wouldn't it be more reasonable to use `QtTest`?

Comment: @JoAreBy - I didn't know about `QtTest`; I'll add that to my answer

Comment: For Qt gui testing I would recommend Squish. IMHO the best you can get for your needs... If it was free. It certainly is not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Test code go to its own source file.

You may split your exe into library and one main.cpp which simply call your library.

That way, you may use any unitTest Framework with extra test files to generate a executable which only tests your library.

Answer (score 0):

For code testing you will use Junit testcase
You may split your exe into library and one main.cpp which simply call your library.

For GUI testing you have do it Manually because there is not Tool Available to Test GUI interface of any application. 
In Manual testing GUI is check complete and GUI image or text is not displayed clearly or text is missing is not all this is will not be test by automation.